# Converting an array into an object

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

I have an array of this fashion:

```
var arr = ["akira",9248,"padilla",100];
```

I'm using `filter` to take the names and the *points*:

```
var names = arr.filter(function(e,i){return i%2 == 0});
var points = arr.filter(function(e,i){return i%2 !== 0});
```

Then I do this to obtain turn it into object:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(_.object(names,points)));
```

What's best in terms of performance/JS quality?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could beat the plain `for` loop: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ws705w5c/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you do it this way which would mean you're only traversing the array once?

```
var obj = {};

for (var i=0; i < arr.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if I could do the same with `reduce`... and I did:

```js
var arr = ["akira",9248,"padilla",100];

var obj = arr.reduce((carry, item, i, array) => {
  if(!(i%2)) carry[item] = array[i+1];
  return carry;
}, {});

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan *"Make sure your answer provides that – **or a viable alternative**. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but **it should also include “try this instead”**" https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Besides, the other guy pretty much already answered a more optimized version, and `reduce` is pretty much self-explanatory if you read what it does.

Comment: But you haven't explained why `reduce` is better or what's bad about the original code. That's what I think you should add. `reduce` may not be self explanatory to the OP, that might be why they didn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

```
var arr = ['akira', 9248, 'padilla', 100];
var obj = {};
var len = arr.length;
for (; len;) {
  obj[arr[--len]] = arr[--len];
}
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

- [A simple `for` is much faster than a `filter`](https://jsperf.com/javascript-array-filter-versus-loop).
- [Iterating through an array backwards is faster than going forward](http://jsperf.com/array-iteration-direction).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: The question is "What's best in terms of performance/JS quality?" and my answer is exactly about performance.